# Como renderizar en la vista una etiqueta de tipo calendario y no un "LabelFor" usando Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, vistas

quiero al renderizar una vista de EntityFramework que para el atributo Datetime Fecha, me muestre en vez de un "@Html.LabelFor", alguno de tipo Calendario:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaNacimiento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaNacimiento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaNacimiento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: y que has intentado???

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].